# Cannot access constant through itemRenderer using parentDocument

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, constants, itemrenderer

I have an itemRenderer inside a dataGrid, and I am able to access variables on the mxml file (in a *.as script file referenced from the mxml) using `parentDocument`. However, I am unable to access a constant in the same script file.  If I change the constant to a regular var, I can access it.

I created a getter function for the constant and it works, but why can't the constant be 
accessed directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are generally static, and therefore access via the class.  Getters / Setters are members, and therefore accessed via an instance.

Therefore, to get access to a constant, you need to have an explicit reference to the class.

Something like `parentDocument.MY_CONSTANT` wouldn't work, however `MyClass(parentDocument).MY_CONSTANT` would.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The parentDocument doesn't need to be part of the solution, but I do need to access the constant directly from the class, as so: MyClass.MY_CONSTANT.